# Can't parse mongoose output in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on an app that takes a list of latitudes and longitudes from a mongodb database and puts them onto a google map as points, but I'm having an issue parsing the JSON that is outputted by mongoose from node.js, here's the code I'm using to parse the JSON. The error that the browser is giving me is:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse('http://hanky-ranky.azurewebsites.net/listbathroom');
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    var bathroom = jsonData[i];
    console.log(bathroom.lat);
}
```

Here's the code I used to generate the JSON inside of node.js using mongoose

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose= require("mongoose");
//Connect to mongo DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://test:test@ds040898.mongolab.com:40898/MongoLab-0');
var myDB = mongoose.connection;

//Error handling if conncetion fails
myDB.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
//Check if successful connection is made
myDB.once('open', function callback () {
  //console.log("MY DB Connected with Mongoose");
});

 //create an employee schema for operation with mongo
var bathroomSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
  'name': String,
  'address' : String,
  'lat': String,
  'lng': String,
  'type': String,
},
{
  collection:'bathrooms'
}
);

// model reference
var bathrooms = mongoose.model('bathrooms', bathroomSchema);

function readBathrooms(callback)
{
  bathrooms.find({},function (error, result) {
    callback(error, result);
  });

}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  readBathrooms(function(error,result){
    if (error) {
      res.send({'result':'error'});
      console.log("Error!");
    }else {               
      //console.log(result);              
      res.render('listbathroom', {"result": result });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here's the jade file that is called for displaying the JSON

```
 !{result}
```

Comment: `res.render('listbathroom', {"result": result });` Is that outputting json? usually you would use `res.json(anobjectorarray)` to output json with express.

Comment: *"but I'm having an issue"* What exactly is the issue? what error occurs? if none, what makes you think there's a problem?

Comment: Just realized I forgot to add the error message, thanks for catching that! It should be on there now

Comment: Just tried your first solution Kevin B, the error still seems to be occurring

Comment: Next question then, what is being returned? Based on that error, my assumption would be it isn't valid json.

Comment: Ah... uhm... `JSON.parse('http://hanky-ranky.azurewebsites.net/listbathroom');` doesn't make an ajax request, it's just going to try to parse `'http://hanky-ranky.azurewebsites.net/listbathroom'` as json, which it clearly isn't, it's just a url... It fails for the same reason `JSON.parse('Hello World!')` fails.

Comment: Oh, OK, that makes so much more sense, never would have guessed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kevin B pointed out to me, I wasn't actually parsing JSON, but instead was attempting to parse a URL as JSON. I solved my problem with the following code

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://hanky-ranky.azurewebsites.net/listbathroom";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var thejson = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    logjson(thejson);
  }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function logjson(arr) {
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i].lat);
  }
}
```